# How do I efficiently web-scrape these abnormal values?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I'm trying to web-scrape items on this page:

https://zkillboard.com/kill/44887120/overview/

Some of it is fairly easy, like if I wanted the amount of dropped ISK I would simply use:

```
dropped = soup.find("td", class_="item_dropped").get_text()
```

which would result in: `13,270,929,632.15 ISK`

However, I want to grab some other values as well but they are more tricky.
Say I want to grab the name of the victim, in this case it is `DwarfMaster`
if I look at the source code for the website it is listed under: `<a href="/character/1248683700/">`

The problem with that is the victim for these pages won't always be `1248683700` and not only this, there are other /characters/numbers on the page representing different characters I don't want to scrape, although they are all in the same position. Is there a better way than just scraping every `<a>` tag and calling the Xth position `/character/` info and then searching tags with that character? It sounds really sloppy. And then there is another tricky scrape on the page, if you look on the right-hand side under `45 Involved` you can see the ship name of players, for example `Silent Ivy`'s ship is a `Nyx` but the only way I can find that value is **inside** of an image link, with no actual text. In this case: `<img class="eveimage img-rounded" width="32" height="32" **alt="Nyx"** src="website.png"></img>` how can I scrape the `alt="Nyx"` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered that the position of the tag you're looking for is fixed on all these pages?

E.g. that "name of the victim" is always accessible under the first anchor of the first table row of the first table within the first table:

```
name = soup.table.table.tr.a.get('title')
```

As for getting the name of that ship, access the `alt` attribute of that `img` tag:

```
import re
shipname = soup.find_all('tr', class_="attacker")[0].find_all('a', href=re.compile('/ship/'))[0].img.get('alt')
```

I used a bit of a detour to access the element, but this should give you an idea on how to access those attributes.